# Zero article before countable nouns in context

Tags: zero-article

I have happened upone it in last episode of [Crash Course A&P](https://youtu.be/rd2cf5hValM). It is at 42 second. Here it goes:

> Now, it becomes the business of your cell-mediated response, or cellular immune response. And that is where stuff gets serious. Where (**a**) cell fights (**a**) cell.

Tell me please why no article was used before the word *cell* there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s perfectly normal speech; the zero article is often used in this manner. One oft-seen example is the phrase *man against man* – which is considered a form of [literary conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_(narrative)#Classification) – but the expression may be found elsewhere as well:

> *Any violence on the part of man against man or man against nature was a violation of Thoreau's pantheistic views*.
>   <sub>(E. A. Moehle - 1972)</sub>

The phrase can be used for other living beings, also, such as in the opening sentence of a 2014 LA Times article:

> *Across the southeastern United States a battle is raging – ant against ant*.

I suppose the fragment could be reworded in a couple ways, and still be grammatical:

- *Where cells fight cells*
- *Where a cell fights a cell*
- *Where cells fight against each other*
- *Where cells fight one-on-one*

But the original has a concise and gritty tone that I think the scriptwriter probably wanted to include.

Answer (score 2):

To omit the article there is a form of generalization.  The noun is generic not specific.  The reference is to the category or class itself, rather than to an instance thereof.

> push comes to shove...
>
> vampire fights werewolf ...
>
> predator becomes prey...
>
> day turns to night ...
>
> neither fish nor fowl...